# NSArray difference between firstObject and objectAtIndex:0

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

In the following example array objectAtIndex:0 crashes but firstObject resulting a nil value. Why this happening?

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray new];
id obj1 = [array firstObject]; // this is giving nil value
id obj2 = [array objectAtIndex:0]; // this line crashes
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using firstObject is a system defined API which returns nil if there is none. But if you try to access objectAtIndex it will give NSRange exception and app will crash.

Answer (score 4):

Because they work, and are documented, differently. It's explicitly stated that that's how they work. `firstObject` is 'safe' in an Obj-C world because it will return `nil` and no-op if there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 3):

In framework, for firstObject method might be have check if array Empty then return nil. But for objectAtIndex: will try fetch object at given index and as array is empty so it's crashing giving reason out of range.

Answer (score 2):

It's a iOS7 feature

[5. Implementation of -[NSArray firstObject]](https://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#firstObject)

```
NSArray *arr = @[]; 
// Before iOS7
id item = [arr count] > 0 ? arr[0] : nil; 
// After iOS7
id item = [arr firstObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between `[array firstObject]` and `array[0]`. The first `firstObject` nil and the second throws an exception when the array is empty. Assuming that firstObject works similarly to lastObject
As a programmer perspective, crashing is not a good thing, so it is better to use `firstObject`.